# Error: docker login -u user [repositorio_nexus]:[puerto]

Tags: docker

Estoy tratando subir mis imágenes de docker al repositorio nexus 3 pero al intentar acceder al repositorio con este comando:

```
docker login -u user [repositorio_nexus]:[puerto]
```

Mando este error:

> Error response from daemon: Get dial tcp getsockopt: connection refused

realicé las indicaciones del siguiente enlace:

http://www.sonatype.org/nexus/2017/02/16/using-nexus-3-as-your-repository-part-3-docker-images/

Comment: ya quedo resuelto, el problema fue que el nexus esta corriendo en un contenedor en el puerto 8081 y cuando queria acceder con docker login a los puertos configurados ( docker-private-> 8085, docker-group-> 8086) para docker en nexus no estaban mapeados en el contenedor cuando se creo la instancia de nexus

Answer (score 0):

¿Podría ser porque no has configurado el proxy para docker, en caso de que uses? De ser así, tienes que añadir las credenciales en /etc/systemd/system/docker...d/proxy.conf

También el problema podría estar en que si has configurado tu repositorio para que funcione con un conector http, tienes que añadir la etiqueta en insecure-registry en daemon.json de docker.